# Build a custom scroll for a textView with a panGestureRecognizer : All programmatically

Tags: ios, uitextview, uipangesturerecognizer

I would like to build a text view (textView) with a custom scroll object (scrollObject), but all programmatically.

This code is OK when I build a textView and a View with the storyboard and when I connect them as Outlets.

But when I build the views programmatically, nothing happens.

Here is the .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong) UITextView *textView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIView *scrollObject;
@property UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan;

@end
```

And here is the .m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITextView *textView =[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 618,1024)];
    [self.view addSubview:textView];

    UIView *scrollObject =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(650, 50, 85, 80)];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollObject];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlepan:)];
    [scrollObject addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}

- (void)handlepan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan {
    static CGPoint initialCenter;
    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        initialCenter = pan.view.center;
    }
    CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:self.view];
    pan.view.center = CGPointMake(initialCenter.x, initialCenter.y + translation.y);
    NSLog(@"_scrollObject.center.y: %f",_scrollObject.center.y); //here is the problem : return 0 !      
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
                _textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, (_scrollObject.center.y)*_textView.contentSize.height/1000);
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Try adding your subviews in `viewWillAppear:` instead of `viewDidLoad`. You usually don't want to set frame properties in `viewDidLoad` because the superview frames haven't been set yet.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, I try it but nothing happens. By the way, when I say nothing happens, it means that the contentOffset of the textView don't interact with the scrollObject. But the scrollObject move (he scrolls vertically).

Comment: I'm kind of confused at what you're trying to accomplish. A `UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, which means it supports scrolling by default. So what are your `scrollObject` and `pan` objects being used for?

Comment: I try to do a differential scrolling. I didn't find other solution, and it works with a storyboard.

Comment: In viewDidLoad, you are declaring _local_ variables textView, scrollObject, and pan.  The _properties_ declared in the header file are never set.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new. If _set the properties_ means @synthesize: I have this message: _the local declaration hides instance variable_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad`, you are declaring *local* variables `textView`, `scrollObject`, and `pan`.

The *properties* declared in the header file are never set so they are `nil` when the gesture recognizer method is called and "nothing happens" when you call methods on `nil`.

In viewDidLoad, `UITextView *textView = ...` is *declaring* a local variable that has no connection to the *property* you declared in the header.

Instead, do `@synthesize`, and in `viewDidLoad`, *set* the property instead:

```
self.textView = ...
```

Do the same for `scrollObject`.

By the way, you don't need to declare `pan` as a property or ivar and I would remove it (leave it as a local variable in `viewDidLoad)`.